# How to kill background process from system function call

Tags: c, system, kill, background-process

How can I kill a background process that was executed using a system function call in C language. Like for example I have a compiled application call "fooprocess". Then I want to write a program that will execute the fooprocess application in the background using the system function, please kindly see below the code,

```
const char app[] = "fooprocess &";
system(app);
```

As you can see there is a "&" character so that I can run the fooprocess application in the background. How can I kill this fooprocess?

Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe `system("pkill fooprocess");`?

Answer (score 5):

To interact with the process you need its PID. I'm not sure if it's possible with `system` but one alternative is to fork the process yourself using fork + exec.

Comment: It's not possible with `system`. If OP's system has `posix_spawn`, it's is probably easier to use than `fork` and `exec`.

Answer (score 3):

You absolutely cannot use `system("foo &");` to create background processes that you can later monitor/kill. Any such use has a **gigantic** inherent bug: even if you know the pid, there is no way to tell if the process with that pid is the process you originally ran, or a completely different process that happened to get the same pid later.

To solve this problem (and countless other problems you don't want to think about or it will make your head hurt) you should forget you ever learned about the `system` function and create your child processes with `fork` and `exec`, or `posix_spawn`. This will result in a direct child process (your current method is creating grandchildren which get orphaned and taken in by the `init` process) which you can `wait`/`waitpid` on, and until you perform a `wait` operation, the child process's pid **belongs to you** and cannot be reused, so it's safe to send signals to it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your problem using this:

```
ps -axc|grep -i myApp|awk '{print $1}' | tr -d '\n' | xargs -0 kill
```

you can place that in system() like so:

```
system("ps -axc|grep -i myApp|awk '{print $1}' | tr -d '\n' | xargs -0 kill");
```

That will work.

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield:  what does that mean? :-)

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that `system` is the wrong tool for the job.  "When all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail."  The right solution is to use `fork`+`exec` instead of `system` to spawn the child process, and then it's much, much easier to interact with that process.